# example of getOwnerType method

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Could I ask about any example which uses [getOwnerType()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getOwnerType--) method where this method would return any Type object, but not a value "null" ?

This is a certain [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.lang.reflect/ParameterizedType/0060__ParameterizedType.getOwnerType_.htm) of use getOwnerType() method which I found in Google:

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

      Type type = StringList.class.getGenericSuperclass();
      System.out.println(type); 
      ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) type;
      Type ownerType = pt.getOwnerType();
      System.out.println(ownerType);
   }
}

class StringList extends ArrayList<String> {

}
```

This is a result:

```
java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
null
```

Everything is fine, because a value of `pt` object is a top-level type and null is returned.

And now, arguably I don't understand these words of documentation:

> Returns a Type object representing the type that this type is a member of. For example, if this type is O< T >.I< S >, return a representation of O< T >.

After reading this, I tried do something like this:

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

      ... // a body of the main method is unchanged
   }
}

class StringList extends ClassA<String>.ClassB<String> {   // line No. 17

}

public class ClassA<T> {
   public class ClassB<T> {

   }
}
```

But, it produces only such error (in line No.17):

```
No enclosing instance of type r61<T> is accessible to invoke the super constructor. Must define a constructor and explicitly qualify its super constructor invocation with an instance of r61<T> (e.g. x.super() where x is an instance of r61<T>).
```

Maybe I tried to do something what doesn't make a sense, but I have no more ideas..

Answer (score 2):

(Courtesy of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

A parameterized type can be found in a class like this:

```
public class ClassA<K,V> {
    // Stuff
}
```

Then, in a main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassA<String,List<String>> test = new ClassA<>("", new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

The paramaterized type is found when initializing ClassA with another class that requires types. In this case, `List<String>` is the paramaterized type.

However, in my own testing, getOwnerType does not have anything to do with the paramaterized type, but instead the class in which it is written.

To explain:

```
public class ClassOne {

    class ClassTwo {

    }

    class ClassThree extends ClassTwo {

    }
}
```

If you ran getOwnerType on ClassThree, it would return ClassOne.

So, in essence, rewrite your first example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Type type = StringList.class.getGenericSuperclass();
        System.out.println(type); 
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) type;
        Type ownerType = pt.getOwnerType();
        System.out.println(ownerType);
    }

    class Dummy<T> {

    }

    class StringList extends Dummy<ArrayList<String>> {

    }
}
```

Your output:

```
 Main.Main$Dummy<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>>
 class Main
```

Not null! Yay!

That's what I got from your question, so I hope this helps! (And, I hope I didn't make any mistakes -_-)

Good luck!